# Expansion inside \AtBeginDocument

Tags: expansion

I'd like to expand a macro inside `\AtBeginDocument`, although I guess the concrete macro does not matter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@for\x:=1,2,3\do{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\@input@{helper\x .tex}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Do something with the definitions from helper1.tex etc. 
\end{document}
```

The file inclusion works without the `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, and of course it does not work with it, as `\x` is not expanded at call time. I have the feeling the right amount of `\expandafter`s in the right places will do the job, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\@for\x:=1,2,3\do{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\AtBeginDocument{\noexpand\@input@{helper\x.tex}}}\x
}
\makeatother
```

Or with `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\clist_map_inline:nn { 1 , 2 , 3 }
 {
  \AtBeginDocument{\@input@{helper#1.tex}}
 }
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: +1 I suppose: you were quicker by a second as `\x` shorter than `\tmp`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's almost automatic; isn't using `\x` with six different meanings lovely?